# Things to check when there is 'no such table' exception in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I defined a new model in django.
It looks like this:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    is_anonymous = False
    is_authenticated = True
```

I've registered the app it is contained under into the settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'lists',
    'accounts',  # <-- this
]
```

I've flushed database, ran `migrate --run-syncdb`, re-made migrations and migrated. So that I do not have any `you have un-applied migrations` messages when running server.

However, the `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table : accounts_user` persists.

I've used shell, and it too throws error:

```
>>> from accounts.models import *
>>> User
<class 'accounts.models.User'>
>>> User.objects
<django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x7fbcbea35ef0>
>>> User.objects
<django.db.models.manager.Manager object at 0x7fbcbea35ef0>
>>> User.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: accounts_user
```

I've exhausted all other options known to me.

Can someone provide a general check-list for things to check (no matter how stupid), when faced with an error like this?

Comment: Did you try python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb?

Comment: Yes, I did. Didn't help.

Comment: but can you see your User model in admin panel?

Comment: I can't even access my admin page due to the same error. I tried resetting admin password and it didn't work.

Comment: Did you check your migrations folder to see what happened when you migrate?

Comment: Migrations folder is exactly the same, no other files around.

Comment: I tried your code in vscode, it doesn't give me any error, in the shell gives me empty queryset[] object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had to re-create the whole dataset.

I had to manually delete the sqlite file and create it anew. After that, the error got away.

It can also be done from `manage.py`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my general check list

1. Check migration files are generated correctly. In your case, please confirm migrations are generated under accounts/migrations and versions
2. If not generated correctly, then generate again using `python manage.py makemigrations` and migrate again `python manage.py migrate`
3. If correct, then review **django_migrations** table.

   `SELECT "_rowid_",* FROM "main"."django_migrations" ORDER BY "_rowid_" ASC`

   And confirm that corresponding accounts_user migration file is executed.